# Uniqueness with has_many on Rails migration (without through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a Rails migration for provinces and countries. The idea is that for each country, we can't allow more than one province with the same name. 
My create_provinces migration is:

```
class CreateProvinces < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    create_table :provinces do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :country, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
end
```

My country.rb is:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :provinces, :uniq => true
end
```

My province.rb is:

```
class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  private
  validates_presence_of :country
  validate :canada_or_usa?
  validates_presence_of :name
  validate :in_right_country?
  validates_associated :country
  def canada_or_usa?
    errors.add(:country, "can only add province for Canada or the United States") unless (country.name == "Canada" || country.name == "United States")
  end
  def in_right_country?
    if country.name == "Canada"
      errors.add(:name, "Name must be the name of a province in Canada") unless (DataHelper::canada_provinces_with_caption.include? name)
    end
    if country.name == "United States"
      errors.add(:name, "Name must be the name of a province in the United States") unless (DataHelper::usa_provinces_with_caption.include? name)
    end
  end
end
```

With `:uniq => true` in country.rb, I am getting the error that says :uniq is not a known key. Note that I also am not using `through` as per other questions. Is there a way to make sure each country can't have two provinces with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that `:uniq => true` does nothing but fake an uniqueness of your data. That adds a DISTINCT clause in the query when getting provinces by `some_country_instance.provinces`. With that you can insert two provinces with the same name for a country. I suggest you remove that. You won't want to be tricked.

What you actually should do is add the pair [country_id, province_name] columns as primary key of your table provinces.

You can accomplish that with a migration with this code:

```
...
def change
   add_index :provinces, [:country_id, :name], unique: true
end
...
```

I'm assuming your table `provinces` has `country_id` as a foreign key column to `countries`, and `name` column holding provinces' name.

To validate data in the model I suggest:

```
...
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :country_id,
           message: "My world my rules. Country cannot have provinces with same name." }
...
```

With that you'll elegantly accomplish your job with few lines of code and taking full advantage of the Rails framework.

Answer (score 0):

In your Province model you need to add

```
validates uniqueness: { scope: :country }
```

This will allow you to have provinces with the same name but not within a single country.

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax would be

```
has_many :provinces, -> { uniq }
```

However this is just defining an association and not actually validating the input to your database. and if you look at sql you will see something like.

```
Select distinct provinces from provinces where provinces.country_id = '';
```